# Xamarin forms Selected Item in List

Tags: xamarin, events, bluetooth, message, selecteditem

Im trying to create project with Bluetooth connection. But when i'm trying to select item in list there are no message: "Do you want to connect to this device?"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7kYy.png)

I manually added the BMW X5 device, but when I click on it, no windows with messages appear

It it my DevicesList_OnItemSelected event:

```
 private async void DevicesList_OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (DevicesList.SelectedItem == null)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Error", "Please select a device from the list first.", "OK");
                return;
            }

            CurDevice = DevicesList.SelectedItem as IDevice;

            if (CurDevice != null)
            {
                if (CurDevice.State == DeviceState.Disconnected)
                {
                    var result = await DisplayAlert("Message", "Do you want to connect to this device?", "Connect", "Cancel");
                    if (result)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            await Adapter.ConnectToDeviceAsync(CurDevice);
                            await DisplayAlert("Message", "Connected to device with Id: " + CurDevice.Id, "OK");
                        }
                        catch (DeviceConnectionException ex)
                        {
                            await DisplayAlert("Error", ex.Message, "OK");
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Error", "Device is already connected or being connected", "OK");
                }
            }
        }
```

`

Comment: is your event handler being called?  Have you stepped through the code in the debugger?

Comment: yes i tryed https://imgur.com/a/WvMorJV

Comment: And does that code execute as expected?  No exceptions?  What happens when it reaches a DisplayAlert?

Comment: no, in fact, when selecting an element, the device should not be null and DisplayAlert should show : "Do you want to join the device?"

Comment: Check the type of `DevicesList.SelectedItem`. Apparently it is NOT an `IDevice`.

Comment: You can try to debug to check the result of the  `CurDevice = DevicesList.SelectedItem as IDevice;`.

Comment: I tryed but Cur Device = null, why if i selected it https://imgur.com/a/WvMorJV

Comment: So you can check the type of DevicesList.SelectedItem as ToolmakerStece said.